Livewire Not working on server.After fixing the JS code,the wire:click functionality is not working and results in a "404 Page Not Found" error
I want to create a project on Laravel Livewire. When I run the project on the server, the Livewire events (wire:navigate, wire:click, wire:ignore) are not working. When I fix the JavaScript, wire:navigate starts working, but the other event (wire:click) does not.
I want it so that when I click wire:click, it should call the method of the Livewire component.
